# Formatting Output with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I'm trying to format my output to look like so

```
PSComputerName       Value
--------------       ------
Computer1           Restricted
Computer2           Unrestricted
Computer3           Unrestricted
```

This is my code the variable $computers points to Get-Content of a file with computer names that I will be connecting to remotely

```
$test = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {
$policy3 = Get-ExecutionPolicy 
Write-Output $policy3
}
write $test
```

The output

```
PSComputerName             RunspaceId                 Value                     
--------------             ----------                 -----                     
Computer1                    7e4ebfbe-62d3-4035-9d5a... Restricted                
Computer2                    2ecd6932-1ed4-4f57-b9e9... Unrestricted              
Computer3                    73a119de-5d6d-4525-9958... Restricted
```

I've been trying to get rid of the RunSpaceId by echoing the invoke-command and doing a foreach of the computer names, I only did PSComputerNames to test if it would work.

```
write $test % {$_.PSComputerName }
```

I know that Invoke-Command has a foreach function built in it but I don't know how to use to my advantage in this situation. What is the best way to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`Select-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) and its capabilities?

Comment: I am and I did try it before but inside the Invoke-Command and for some reason it did not display anything for PSComputerName or Value and it was disordered however I just tried it outside the invoke-command and it did in fact work. @BACON Thanks!

Comment: The `PSComputerName` and `RunspaceId` properties are added by `Invoke-Command` which is why you can only access them (or strip them off) outside of the call to `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PS> Invoke-Command $computers { Get-ExecutionPolicy } |
      Format-Table PSComputerName, Value

PSComputerName  Value                     
--------------  -----                     
Computer1       Restricted                
...
```

As [BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon) points out in comments on the question, it is `Invoke-Command` that implicitly adds the `PSComputerName` and `RunSpaceId` properties to the objects returned by the script block (`{ ... }`) run on each target computer, and whether they are *displayed* by default depends on the type of the object returned.
In the case of the `[Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]` instances returned by `Get-ExecutionPolicy`, they *are* displayed by default, which means that in order to *display* only the properties of interest you need an explicit `Format-*` call.

Note that an automatically added `Value` property is an artifact of the remotely executed script block returning an instance of an `[enum]`-derived type, such as the instances of `[Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]` returned by `Get-ExecutionPolicy`.

Remotely invoked `Invoke-Command` script blocks outputting non-primitive-.NET-type instances return *deserialized* objects of type `Deserialized.<original-type-name>`.
`[enum]`-derived instances  result in a deserialized type with a `Value` property defined as a `ScriptProperty` member with signature `System.Object Value {get=$this.ToString();}`; for general information about how serialization and deserialization works in PowerShell remoting and background jobs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

---

General tips:

- `Write-Output` is generally not needed, because the output of any statement that is not captured in a variable or redirected to a file / to `$null` is *implicitly* sent to the output stream.
- If you ever need to write cross-platform-compatible code, avoid aliases such as `write`, because they won't work as expected on Unix-like platforms in PowerShell Core, where aliases that would shadow native utilities aren't defined.