# Unexpected variable type returned by Receive-Job

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to execute the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command (from the [SqlServer module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15)) to run a query as a different AD user. I know there's the `-Credential` argument, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thus, I thought using `Start-Job` might be an option, as shown in the snippet below.

```
$username = 'dummy_domain\dummy_user'
$userpassword = 'dummy_pwd' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Import-Module SqlServer; Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "exec sp_who" -ServerInstance 'dummy_mssql_server' -As DataSet} -Credential $credential

$data = Receive-Job -Job $job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

However, when looking at the variable type that the job returned, it isn't what I expected.

```
> $data.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSObject

> $data.Tables[0].GetType().FullName
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

If I run the code in the `ScriptBlock` directly, these are the variable types that PS returns:

```
> $data.GetType().FullName
System.Data.DataSet

> $data.Tables[0].GetType().FullName
System.Data.DataTable
```

I tried casting the `$data` variable to `[System.Data.DataSet]`, which resulted in the following error message:

```
Cannot convert value "System.Data.DataSet" to type "System.Data.DataSet". 
Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Data.DataSet" value of type 
"Deserialized.System.Data.DataSet" to type "System.Data.DataSet"."
```

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to run SQL queries under a different AD account, using the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command?
2. Is there a way to get the correct/expected variable type to be returned when calling `Receive-Job`?

**Update**

When I run `$data.Tables | Get-Member`, one of the properties returned is:

```
Tables  Property  Deserialized.System.Data.DataTableCollection {get;set;}
```

Comment: This _is_ expected - jobs run in separate processes, so the data has to be serialized and de-serialized before it gets back to you

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Does that mean that something is going wrong with the variable types when the object is being de-serialized? Is there any way to de-serialize the object exactly how it was before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 2. Is there a way to get the correct/expected variable type to be returned when calling `Receive-Job`?

**Due to using a background job, you lose type fidelity**: the objects you're getting back are method-less *emulations* of the original types.

Manually recreating the original types is not worth the effort and may not even be possible - though perhaps working with the emulations is enough.

*Update*: As [per your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59246643/45375), switching from working with `System.DataSet` to `System.DataTable` resulted in serviceable emulations for you.<sup>[1]</sup>

See the bottom section for more information.

> 1. Is there a better way to run SQL queries under a different AD account, using the Invoke-Sqlcmd command?

**You need an *in-process* invocation method in order to maintain type fidelity**, but I don't think that is possible with arbitrary commands if you want to *impersonate another user*.

For instance, the in-process (thread-based) alternative to `Start-Job` - `Start-ThreadJob` - doesn't have a `-Credential` parameter.

Your best bet is therefore to try to make [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/Invoke-Sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)'s `-Credential` parameter work for you or find a different in-process way of running your queries with a given user's credentials.

---

#### Serialization and deserialization of objects in background jobs / remoting / mini-shells:

Whenever PowerShell marshals objects **across *process boundaries***, it employs **XML-based *serialization* at the source, and *deserialization* at the destination**, using a format known as **CLI XML** (Common Language Infrastructure XML).

This happens in the context of **PowerShell remoting** (e.g., [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) calls with the
`-ComputerName` parameter) as well as in **background jobs** ([`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)) and so-called **mini-shells** (which are implicitly used when you call the PowerShell CLI from inside PowerShell itself *with a script block*; e.g., `powershell.exe { Get-Item / }`).

**This deserialization maintains *type fidelity* only for a *limited set of known types***, as specified in [MS-PSRP, the PowerShell Remoting Protocol Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-psrp/b2baf403-78aa-4f41-b140-cc4f5090cd68). That is, only instances of a fixed set of types are deserialized *as their original type*.

**Instances of all other types are *emulated***: list-like types become `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instances, dictionary types become `[hasthable]` instances, and other types **become method-less (properties-only) *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances)**, whose `.pstypenames` property contains the original type name prefixed with `Deserialized.` (e.g., `Deserialized.System.Data.DataTable`), as well as the equally prefixed names of the type's *base* types (inheritance hierarchy).

Additionally, the ***recursion depth* for object graphs of *non*-`[pscustomobject]` instances is limited to `1` level** - note that this includes instance of [PowerShell custom *classes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes), created with the `class` keyword: That is, if an input object's property values aren't instance of well-known types themselves (the latter includes single-value-only types, including .NET primitive types such as `[int]`, as opposed to types composed of multiple properties), they are replaced by their `.ToString()` representations (e.g., type `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` has a `.Parent` property that is another `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instance, which means that the `.Parent` property value serializes as the `.ToString()` representation of that instance, which is its full path string); in short: **Non-custom (scalar) objects serialize such that property values that aren't themselves instances of well-known types are *replaced by their `.ToString()` representation***; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808632/45375) for a concrete example.
By contrast, *explicit* use of CLI XML serialization via **[`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml) defaults to a depth of `2`** (you can specify a custom depth via `-Depth` and you can similarly control the depth if you use the underlying [`System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer) type *directly*).

Depending on the original type, you *may* be able to reconstruct instances of the original type *manually*, but that is not guaranteed.
(You can get the original type's full name by calling `.pstypenames[0] -replace '^Deserialized\.'` on a given custom object.)

Depending on your processing needs, however, the *emulations* of the original objects may be sufficient.

---

<sup>[1] Using `System.DataTable` results in usable emulated objects, because you get a `System.Collections.ArrayList` instance that emulates the table, and custom objects with the original property values for its `System.DataRow` instances. The reason this works is that PowerShell has built-in logic to treat `System.DataTable` implicitly as an *array of its data rows*, whereas the same doesn't apply to `System.DataSet`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for question 2 as I've never used the job commands but when it comes to running the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` I always make sure that the account that runs the script has the correct access to run the SQL.

The plus to this is that you don't need to store the credentials inside the script, but is usually a moot point as the scripts are stored out of reach of most folks, although some bosses can be nit picky!

Out of curiosity how do the results compare if you pipe them to `Get-Member`?

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, below is the code I implemented. Depending on whether or not `$credential` is passed, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` will either run directly, or using a background job.

I had to use `-As DataTables` instead of `-As DataSet`, as the latter seems to have issues with serialisation/deserialisation (see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/3165737) for more info).

```
function Exec-SQL($server, $database, $query, $credential) {

    $sqlData = @()

    $scriptBlock = {
        Param($params)

        Import-Module SqlServer
        return Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $params.server -Database $params.database -query $params.query -As DataTables -OutputSqlErrors $true
    }

    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("credential")) {

        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -Credential $credential -ArgumentList $PSBoundParameters
        $sqlData = Receive-Job -Job $job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

    } else {
        $sqlData = & $scriptBlock -params $PSBoundParameters
    }
    return $sqlData
}
```

Comment: Good to know that using `System.DataTable` resulted in usable emulated objects (you'll get a `System.Collections.ArrayList` instance for the table, and custom objects for its `System.DataRow` instances. The reason this works is that PowerShell has built-in logic to treat `System.DataTable` implicitly as an array of its data rows, whereas the same doesn't apply to `System.DataSet`.