# Local statement output very different than invoke-command output

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Logged in to the system directly, I run this statement, and get this output:

```
(Get-ClusterNetwork 'cluster backups').role
None
```

This is perfect... beautiful even, in it's simplicity.

However, when I run the exact same statement from a remote machine using invoke-command, which up until now i always just assumed was like typing this exact statement into the CLI of the machine, I get THIS output instead

```
Invoke-Command -Session $hi -ScriptBlock {(Get-ClusterNetwork 'cluster backups').role}
PSComputerName RunspaceId                           Value
-------------- ----------                           -----
dumdum a84b6c89-dumdum-80d3-ed43230ee8ab            None
```

Now here's the really funny thing. If i assign a variable to the invoke-command output, it'll have the same output shown above UNLESS - i pipe it to **set-clipboard**

So the variable

```
$hello = invoke-command -session $hi -scriptblock {(get-networkcluster 'cluster backups').role}
```

Now type $hello into prompt and I get:

```
PSComputerName RunspaceId                           Value
-------------- ----------                           -----
dumdum a84b6c89-dumdum-80d3-ed43230ee8ab            None
```

Which is expected. But now when I pipe that to **set-clipboard** and paste - the value is:

```
$hello | set-clipboard;
get-clipboard
None
```

Which is the actual value I want. Somehow piping to set-clipboard knows to only pull the property that i originally asked for. Even though the variable, has all the properties. When i run $hello.gettype() - i see the value as **Int32**. Which makes sense if $hello was only returning the value I wanted, but it's... not.

But if that wasn't weird enough - I'm running a few functions within the invoke-command, this is only one piece - all of the functions return a value i'm trying to report on. So:

```
$row = '' | select computername, ClusterNetworkRole, IP;
$row.computername = $name;
$row.clusternetworkrole = $hello;
$row.ip = dum.dum.dum.dum;
Return $row;
```

Do you know what the output of $row.clusternetworkrole is? Take a wild guess.
It's every property EXCEPT the one I want.

```
$row
PSComputerName     : dumdum
RunspaceId         : b898bdad-dumdum-9eff-8a2beeefe78a
ClusterNetworkRole :
Computername       : dum
IP                 : dum.dum.dum.dum
```

Not only does it give me the exact properties i DON'T want - it actually adds those properties as members of $row.

```
$row.RunspaceID
b898bdad-dumdum-9eff-8a2beeefe78a
```

Now i can get the value i want by appending ".value" at the end of the statement, so this isn't so much a problem to be solved as much as it is a question of just what the hell powershell is doing. It's taken this simple, beautiful tiny statement - and wreaked havoc on my life.

Comment: the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet [when run with `-ComputerName` or `-Session`] will always add the following properties >>> `PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, RunspaceId` <<< if you don't want them, then you will need to remove them. the simplest way is to pipe the object to  >>> `Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, RunspaceId` <<<

Comment: ah - it only throws back the pscomputername and runspaceID in $row. But that's, interesting. Cause any other time i've assigned a variable to the invoke-command output, i've never seen those properties returned. But ok, thanks

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] i found it out when i used `Select-Object` to add a calculated prop & then used `Export-Csv` ... and found those props. [*grin*] now i usually either explicitly build the desired `PSCustomObject` OR use the code snippet i showed previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In your specific case* of an instance of an **enum value** (an instance of a **`System.Enum`-derived type**):

- Use `[int] $hello` to get the *numeric value* of the original, enum (`System.Enum`-derived) value, without the extra `NoteProperty` members such as `PSComputerName` that the remoting infrastructure adds (see below).
- Use `$hello.Value` to get the *string* representation of the enum value (its symbolic *name* rather than its *number*).
- If you know the original `System.Enum`-derived type, and that type is also available in your local session, you can *cast* the deserialized object back to its original type; e.g.:
  `[Microsoft.Foo.Bar.ClusterRole] $hello`
- `$hello` is technically an `[int]`, but decorated with extra properties, and information about the *original* type recorded in the hidden `.pstypenames` array, which reflects the original type's inheritance hierarchy with the type names prefixed with `Deserialized.`; e.g. `Deserialized.Microsoft.Foo.Bar.ClusterRole`; PowerShell's output formatting system causes such an object to be formatted via (implicitly applied) `Format-Table`, which in this case shows everything *but* the actual `[int]` value - only the `NoteProperty` members are shown.

*Generally*, you can **exclude the unwanted properties** as follows:

- For `[string]` instances only, you can access `.psobject.BaseObject` to get the underlying object without any `NoteProperty` members.
- For others, you can create a *new* object (invariably of type `[pscustomobject]`), by piping to `Select-Object` with the unwanted properties *excluded*, as suggested by [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey)):

  - `$hello | Select-Object * -Exclude PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, RunspaceId`
  - Alternatively, you can focus on selecting just the properties you *do* want.

Read on for why that is necessary.

---

**PowerShell's remoting infrastructure *decorates* every object returned from a remote invocation** with the following `NoteProperty` [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) members:

- `PSComputerName` ... the name of the remote computer
- `RunspaceId` ... the ID of the runspace in which the remote command executed.
- `PSShowComputerName` ... a *hidden* property that, when set to `$true` on all objects returned via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s **`-HideComputerName`** switch, suppresses *display* of the `PSComputerName` property in the default output (but the property is still there); you can only see the `PSShowComputerName` itself if you pipe a remotely received object to `Get-Member -Force`.
- Additionally, `System.Enum`-derived types, which are returned as `[int]` instances, are decorated with a `[string]`-typed `Value` `NoteProperty` that contains the enum value's *symbolic name* (the enum's *type* name can be inferred from `.pstypenames[0] -replace '^Deserialized\.'`).

The `PSComputerName` and `RunspaceId` properties are useful in remoting commands that target *multiple* computers at once: given that the order in which output is received is not guaranteed, these properties tell you where a given output object originated from.

The `PSShowComputerName` property allows you to control default display behavior - though, curiously, it has no effect on whether `RunspaceId` is displayed.

The `Value` property for `System.Enum`-derived types compensates for the **loss of type fidelity that typically occurs in remoting commands** (and background jobs) - only a limited set of known types deserialize with type fidelity - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

---

While these properties always *exist*, whether they *show by default* depends on the specific types of the object returned and either what formatting data is associated with them or applied by default by PowerShell.

Also, they may show when you pipe to `Format-*` cmdlets explicitly, and during serialization, such as with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work, if you don't want the computername:

```
(invoke-command $hi {Get-ClusterNetwork 'cluster backups'}).role
```