# Inconsistent PowerShell when command is called via Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I've got a simple Get-ScheduledTask command that gives me a simple output:

```
    Get-ScheduledTask | select -last 1
    
    TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
    --------                                       --------                          -----
    \Microsoft\Windows\WS\                         WSTask                            Ready
```

When I call this same command through Invoke-Command (run from and on the same computer as above), I sometimes get a very similar output:

```
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName PRD-APIEXT001 -ScriptBlock {Get-ScheduledTask |select -last 1 } -Credential $cred
    
    TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State      PSComputerName
    --------                                       --------                          -----      --------------
    \Microsoft\Windows\WS\                         WSTask                            Ready      PRD-APIEXT001
```

But sometimes, I get a *much* more verbose output:

```
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName PRD-APIEXT001 -ScriptBlock {Get-ScheduledTask |select -last 1} -Credential $cred
    
    
    PSComputerName     : PRD-APIEXT001
    RunspaceId         : [REDACTED]
    Actions            : {MSFT_TaskComHandlerAction}
    Author             : Microsoft Corporation
    Date               : 2010-10-27T17:18:44.0816608
    Description        : Windows Store Maintenance Task
    Documentation      :
    Principal          : MSFT_TaskPrincipal2
    SecurityDescriptor : [REDACTED]
    Settings           : MSFT_TaskSettings3
    Source             : wsservice.dll
    State              : 3
    TaskName           : WSTask
    TaskPath           : \Microsoft\Windows\WS\
    Triggers           :
    URI                : \Microsoft\Windows\WS\WSTask
    Version            :
```

I can figure out no rhyme or reason why it's sometimes the simple output, and sometimes the verbose output, except that it only seems to change in one direction; from verbose to simple.  That is, once a PowerShell session shows the simple output, it never seems to go back to the verbose output.  But sometimes a session that used to be showing verbose output will switch to the simple.

Now, I know from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328826/local-statement-output-very-different-than-invoke-command-output) that Invoke-Command adds properties to each object that it returns.

But I am still at a loss as to why it would sometimes give the the table-based output and sometimes give me a list of properties as the output.

Can anybody tell me what might be happening here?

I am using PowerShell version 5.1.14409.1018.

Comment: The remote computer is always the same?

Comment: Yes, and it's the same computer I'm running the command from.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like until the ScheduledTasks module is loaded, either with import-module or running get-scheduledtask locally, the display info for that type of object isn't loaded.

```
Import-Module ScheduledTasks
icm localhost { get-scheduledtask | select -last 1 }  # elevated prompt for localhost

TaskPath                                       TaskName
--------                                       --------
\Microsoft\XblGameSave\                        XblGameSaveTaskLogon


Get-ScheduledTask | select -last 1 | get-member | findstr TypeName

TypeName: 
'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_ScheduledTask'
```