# How to set local variables inside remote session?

Tags: powershell

I'm running a script inside Invoke-Command. I have a global variable in my local session that got many configurations. I'm passing this object to Invoke-Command. How do I set a property inside that object in the remote session?

Comment: Are you hoping that assigning to a property in the remote session will be reflected on the object in your local session?

Comment: In short: you can't (assuming you want the new property value to be seen _by the caller_). instead, _output (return) data_ from your remote call, which you can then assign to a local variable.

Comment: Using return method, what if I want to set multiple properties?

Comment: Return a whole object, they can have multiple properties :)

Comment: There is also [multiple variable assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.2#assigning-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you're trying to do fundamentally cannot work:**

- A script block that runs *remotely* of necessity **runs in a *different process*** (on a different machine).<sup>[1]</sup>
- **You can only pass a *copy* of a local object to a remotely executing script block** - either via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-ArgumentList` parameter or via a [`$using:` reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) inside the script block, but **whatever modifications you make to that copy are *not* seen by the caller**.

---

The **solution** is to ***output* (return) the data** of interest from the remotely executed script block, which you can **then (re)assign to a local variable** on the caller's side.

- **Note**: Due to the limitations of the XML-based *serialization* that PowerShell employs across process / computer boundaries, what is being passed and/or returned is situationally only a (method-less) *emulation* of the original object; that is, type fidelity cannot be guaranteed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for background information.

For example:

```
# Define a local object.
$localObject = [pscustomobject] @{ Prop = 42 }

# Pass a *copy* of that object to a remotely executing script block,
# modify it there, then *output* the *modified copy* and
# assign it back to the local variable.
$localObject =
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName someServer {
    $objectCopy = $using:localObject
    # Modify the copy.
    $objectCopy.Prop++
    # Now *output* the modified copy.
   $objectCopy
 }
```

Note that while type fidelity *is* maintained in this simple example, the object  returned is *decorated with remoting-related properties*, such as `.PSComputerName` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330747/45375)

---

<sup>[1] Passing objects *as-is* to a different runspace, so that updates to it are also seen by the caller, works only if the other runspace is a *thread* in the *same process*, such as when you use `Start-ThreadJob` and `ForEach-Object -Parallel`, and even then only if the object is an instance of a *.NET reference type*. Also, if there's a chance that multiple runspaces try to update the given object *in parallel*, you need to manage concurrency explicitly in order to avoid thread-safety issues.</sup>