# Powershell script to extract a list of servers/computers from a .txt file and then display status and then export to CSV?

Tags: powershell, server, agent, powershell-remoting, remoting

I have a list of 140 servers in a txt file and need to check status of Crowdstrike on each of them and then export to CSV. Would the below be correct?

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\servers.txt

ForEach($Computer in $Computers){
Get-Service -Displayname "Crowdstrike Falcon Sensor Service"| select Status | export-csv c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
}
```

I have tried the above and resulted in error.

Comment: You're looping thru the `$Computers` but you're never telling `Get-Service` you want to query a remote host so no, it will give you local information

Comment: Hmmmmmm....perhaps below instead?

Get-Content -Path C:\temp\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {-Displayname "Crowdstrike Falcon Sensor Service"} | select Status | export-csv c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, you're not using your iteration variable, `$Computer`, in the loop body, so all `Get-Service` calls are made *locally*.

- In ***Windows PowerShell*, select *purpose-specific cmdlets* such as `Get-Service` *themselves* have a `-ComputerName` parameter**, so the following *may* work for you:

  ```bash
  # Windows PowerShell only. 
  # If this doesn't work, see the Invoke-Command solution below.
  Get-Service -Computer $Computers -Displayname 'Crowdstrike Falcon Sensor Service' | 
    Select-Object MachineName, Status |
    Export-csv c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
  ```
- In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), these cmdlet-individual `-ComputerName` parameters are no longer supported**, because they **relied on the obsolete [.NET Remoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.71)) APIs**<sup>[1]</sup> that were removed from the modern, cross-platform .NET (Core) framework that underlies PowerShell (Core).

  - Now, **only the *general-purpose remoting cmdlets* ([`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command), [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession))** and the **CIM cmdlets (e.g. [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)) have `-ComputerName` parameters and use PowerShell's *[WinRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Management)-based* [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Requirements), which is *firewall-friendly***.

    - PowerShell remoting is enabled by default in *server* editions of Windows, starting with Windows Server 2012.
  - Therefore - assuming the target servers are set up for PowerShell remoting - use the following (also works in Windows PowerShell):

    ```bash
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers { 
      Get-Service -Displayname 'Crowdstrike Falcon Sensor Service' 
    } | 
      Select-Object MachineName, Status |
      Export-csv c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
    ```

---

Note:

- Both solutions take advantage of the fact that `-ComputerName` accepts an *array* of computer names, which not only shortens the code but allows the computers to be targeted *in parallel*.

  - However, note that the order of output objects will typically *not* reflect the input order of computer names.
- The `MachineName` property was added to the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call in order to identify each originating computer in the output file.

  - The `MachineName` property is a *native member* of the [`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.machinename) instances that [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) emits, and, similarly, types output by other cmdlets that build on the obsolete *.NET Remoting* in Windows PowerShell, such as [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process), as emitted by [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process), have this property.
  - Independently, *PowerShell remoting* uses PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) to *decorate* all output objects with a `PSComputerName` property (among others, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330747/45375)), which allows identifying an output object's computer of origin *irrespective of its type*.

---

<sup>[1] If either endpoint was a non-.NET component, this form of remoting relied on *DCOM* - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973864(v=msdn.10)#net-remoting-scenarios).</sup>