# Why am I not getting PSComputerName value in one out of two scenarios given?

Tags: powershell

Why am I not getting PSComputerName value in one out of two scenarios given?
In the first scenario, I'm not getting a PSComputerName but I am getting the Free and Used.
However, in 2nd scenario, I'm getting the name, smh

**Input**

```
$computers = 
@"
Server1
"@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

$oRes1 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {

    $test = 
    @{ 
        res1 = Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object PSComputerName,Used,Free;
    }

    $test
}

$oRes1
```

**Output**

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
res1                           @{PSComputerName=; Used=130975477760; Free=136250949632}
```

**Input**

```
$computers = 
@"
Server1
"@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

$oRes1 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {

    Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object PSComputerName,Used,Free
}

$oRes1
```

**Output**

```
Used           : 130977939456
Free           : 136248487936
PSComputerName : Server1
RunspaceId     : blah
```

Comment: try changing `$test = @{ ....` to `$test = [pscustomobject]@{ ...`

Answer (score 1):

`PSComputerName` and `RunspaceId` are still there if you return a `Hashtable` (first example) instead of a `PSCustomObject` (second example), it's just that you don't see them due to the default view. Those properties are attached to the [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) wrapper, something very similar to this:

```bash
$hash = @{ foo = 'bar' }
$hash.PSObject.Properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new('PSComputerName', $env:COMPUTERNAME))
$hash
# we don't see it:
#
# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# foo                            bar
#
# but its there:
$hash.PSComputerName
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- All **output objects received via PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote)** are automatically and invariably ***decorated*<sup>[1]</sup> with a `PSComputerName` property**, among others,<sup>[2]</sup> **on *being returned to the caller*, unbeknownst to the remotely executing code.**

  - These properties may not always show in the *display output*, but they're there.

    - As pointed out in [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77483737/45375), even the `[hashtable]` instance returned from your first snippet has a `.PSComputerName` property - but not as a hashtable *entry*, which is why it didn't show in the default *for-display formatting*.
  - It is only the `.PSComputerName` property that is shown *by default* (unless overridden by explicit formatting data, such as in the case of hashtables). You can request it not be shown with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-HideComputerName` parameter.
- If you want to **refer to the *values* that these properties will be filled with *from inside the remotely executing script block***, use the properties of the same name of the [automatic **`$PSSenderInfo`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pssenderinfo), such as `$PSSenderInfo.PSComputerName`, as shown below.

---

To **make your first, hashtable-based snippet work**:

- Obtain the value of what will become the `PSComputerName` property value via `$PSSenderInfo.PSComputerName`
- Use that value in a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) in your [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call.

```bash
# ... inside your remotely executing script block
$test = @{
  res1 = 
    Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object @{
        Name = 'PSComputerName'
        Expression = { $PSSenderInfo.PSComputerName }
      }, Used, Free
}
```

---

**`Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object PSComputerName, Used, Free` when used *directly* - without the `$test` hashtable wrapper - *happens to work by lucky accident***:

- Because `PSComputerName` isn't a property of the objects output by `Get-PSDrive`, the value of the `.PSComputerName` property on the object output by `Select-Object` is *originally* `$null`, on the remote side.
- In effect, the remoting infrastructure then fills that property in on *returning* the object from the remote script block.
- Therefore, simplifying your command to the following would work too - when the caller receives the object, it will have a `PSComputerName` property reflecting the name of the remote machine:

  ```bash
  Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Used, Free
  ```

---

<sup>[1] via a `NoteProperty` [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) member</sup>

<sup>[2] See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330747/45375) for an overview of all these properties.</sup>