# Does PowerShell support HashTable Serialization?

Tags: powershell, serialization, hashmap, hashtable, pickle

If I want to write an object / HashTable to disk and load it up again later does PowerShell support that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can use PowerShell's [native `CliXml` format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml):

```bsh
@{
  a = 1
  b = [pscustomobject]@{
    prop = "value"
  }
} | Export-Clixml -Path hashtable.ps1xml
```

Deserialize with [`Import-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml):

```
PS C:\> $ht = Import-CliXml hashtable.ps1xml
PS C:\> $ht['b'].prop -eq 'value'
True
```

Comment: Indeed; worth mentioning the potential loss of type fidelity during serialization/deserialization (not a concern with your example) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

Answer (score 3):

As the default PowerShell hash table (`@{...}`) is of type `Object`, `Object` it doesn't concern just a `HashTable` type but the question implies serializing of *any* (value) type to disk.

In addition to the answer from [@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), you might use the PowerShell serializer ([**System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psserializer?view=pscore-6.2.0)) for this:

**Serialize to disk**

```
[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($HashTable) | Out-File .\HashTable.txt
```

**Deserialize from disk**

```
$PSSerial = Get-Content .\HashTable.txt
$HashTable = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($PSSerial)
```

You could also use this [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) cmdlet. The downside is that is concerns a non-standard PowerShell cmdlet for serializing but the advantage is that you might use the standard and easy [**dot-sourcing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) technique to restore it:

**Serialize to disk**

```
$HashTable | ConvertTo-Expression | Out-File .\HashTable.ps1
```

**Deserialize from disk**

```
$HashTable = . .\HashTable.ps1
```

Comment: FWIW, `[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize()` produces the exact same format as `Export-Clixml`

Answer (score 2):

The answer may depend on the data in your hashtable. For relatively simple data
`Export-Clixml` and `Import-CliXml` is the native and straightforward
PowerShell solution, see another answer.

For more complex data, not well serialized via `CliXml`, but .NET serializable,
you may use one of the standard .NET serializers. For example, `BinaryFormatter`.
You may use (or learn the code) two ready scripts: [Export-Binary.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Export-Binary.ps1) and [Import-Binary.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Import-Binary.ps1).
You may find demo examples, including the hashtable, in [Export-Binary.test.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Demo/Export-Binary.test.ps1).

And, if you want to store *many hashtables* effectively then look for some sort
of document store solutions. I recently found that LiteDB is very good for many
PowerShell scenarios. So I created [Ldbc](https://github.com/nightroman/Ldbc), the PowerShell wrapper of LiteDB, batteries included.
Using this way, you may store and retrieve thousands of hashtables.

UPDATE: If you prefer to store *relatively simple data* in PSD1 (native PowerShell data format), you may also use the script module [PsdKit](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsdKit). (Thank you @iRon for reminding)