# powershell, how to safely store variable type for future use

Tags: powershell

I load some config from a JSON file and I want to be able to check what I've just loaded and potentially set some default values.

for now, I create a hash table containing info then load and check this way

```
$config_info=@{
    foo=@{default='' ;type=[string]}
    bar=@{default=@();type=[array] }
}

$config = Get-Content $configPath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

if(-not [Bool]$config.PSObject.Properties['foo']) {
    $config | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'foo' -Value $config_info.foo.default 
}

if($config.foo -isnot $config_info.foo.type) { ... }
```

but I'm wondering how safe is the notation `type=[string]` and if I should rather use `type=''.getType()` witch looks less natural.

### Update 1

in the past I used `Export-Clixml`/`Import-Clixml` for my config files but the resulting files are hardly human readable/ editable.

I also sometimes used dot-sourcing PS1 files but for the current project, config has to be maintain by non-powershell people.

What I'm wondering is, is `type=[string]` a safe/ lasting syntax to store `''.getType()` in a variable, or not.

Comment: What are you trying to guard against? Are you worrying that `[string]` will one day no longer describe a type-literal?

Comment: See: [Does PowerShell support HashTable Serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60621582/1701026)

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve here... I'd argue that PowerShell is the wrong language if you want your data types immutable and static. Why are you concerned that your string data type might change?

Comment: With your update, the question is still **Why?** PowerShell is a loosely language by nature. E.g. there is no reason to use the `[bool]` [conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06) in `-not [Bool]$config.PSObject.Properties['foo']`, it will automatically type cast depending on the operator and the left operant.

Comment: You might also create a `.psd1` file (see: [Import-PowerShellDataFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile)) which requires less PowerShell knowledge, is safe and supports limited value types.

Comment: To validate JSON you may want to use JsonSchema instead of reinventing the wheel. PowerShell supports it through the [`Test-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-7.3#example-2-test-an-object-against-a-provided-schema) command since PS 6.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm wondering is, is `type=[string]` a safe/ lasting syntax to store `''.getType()` in a variable, or not.

- Yes, assuming that the .NET `[string]` type ([`System.String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)) isn't being *shadowed* by a custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) definition of the same name (which would be unwise to do).
- `[string]` is a [PowerShell *type literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375), and referring to a .NET type this way works predictably, *assuming the type has been loaded into the session*, which is by definition true for built-in types such as `System.String`. You can refer to a .NET type:

  - by its [*accelerator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) name, if defined; such as `[string]` or `[regex]`; use the `.FullName` property to see the type's full name; e.g. `[regex].FullName`
  - by its *full name*, though note that you're free to omit the `System.` part of the namespace, e.g., you can refer to [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding) as `[System.Text.Encoding]` or `[Text.Encoding]`
  - by its *assembly-qualified name*; e.g. (obtained with
    `[string].AssemblyQualifiedName`):

    ```
    [System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]`
    ```

    - However:

      - This doesn't work across PowerShell editions, at least not for built-in types.
      - It is rarely necessary and can give the false impression that a given assembly version is being referenced (.NET seemingly loads whatever version is available)
      - However, in *.NET (Core) / PowerShell (Core) only*, you may *omit* the `Version` field; similarly, `Culture` and `PublicKeyToken` are optional.
      - While I doubt the need will arise, especially with respect to built-in types, at least hypothetically you can then disambiguate types with the same full name by their hosting assembly; e.g.:

        ```
         # PS Core (v7+) only; the PublicKeyToken field may be omitted.
         [System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]
        ```

---

**A simpler *[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)* solution:**

- In PowerShell (Core) 7+, [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) has an `-AsHashtable` switch returns the parsing results as *hashtables* rather than as `[pscustomobject]` instances.
- Given that you can cast from a hashtable to a custom `class` type literal, you can use strongly typed properties with default values that correspond to the properties in the input JSON data.

```
# Custom class that describes the structure of the config data,
# with strongly typed properties and default values.
class Config {
   [string] $foo = '(none)'
   [int[]] $bar = @()
}

# Sample JSON input; parse it into a hashtable.
$ht = @'
{
  "bar": [1, 2]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

# Construct a [Config] instance from the values in the hashtable,
# enforcing data types, with on-demand conversion.
[Config] $ht
```

Output (note how `foo` has its default value):

```
foo    bar
---    ---
(none) {1, 2}
```

Note:

- PowerShell's flexible automatic type conversions are used when constructing the `Config` instance, and given that PowerShell's allows *any* data type to be converted to `[string]`, non-string input for `[string]`-typed properties is still accepted (resulting in stringification).
- When a value is of the wrong type and cannot be converted (e.g., a value of `"abc"` for an `[int]`-typed property), the `[Config]` cast results in a statement-terminating error.
- If you need more stringent type-checking, consider using validation by a *JSON schema*, which [`Test-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json) supports via the `-Schema` and `-SchemaFile` parameters, in PowerShell (Core) only, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) suggests.