# Run one PowerShell script from another without inheriting variables and scope

Tags: powershell

Normally in PowerShell this works:

```bsh
# parent.ps1

$x = 1
&"$PSScriptRoot/child.ps1"
```

```bsh
# child.ps1

Write-Host $x
```

When `parent.ps1` runs, it prints out `1` since `child.ps1` has inherited it.

Can I prevent this for my script?

I can do `$private:x = 1`, but parent has many variables, so it's verbose and error-prone.

Is there a way to call `child.ps1` without inheriting scope?
Or maybe a way to mark *everything* in parent private?

Comment: Would starting another Powershell process be an option?

Comment: Maybe, I am a bit concerned if parent can run in either powershell.exe or pwsh.exe I would need to know which one to start?

Comment: `$host` is your friend. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, short of defining all variables in the calling scope (and its ancestral scopes) with the `$private:` scope, you cannot prevent PowerShell's dynamic scoping.

That is, creating a variable in a given scope (without `$private:`) makes it visible to all its descendant scopes, such as the child scope in which a script (invoked directly or via `&`) runs.

Also, certain automatic (built-in) variable are defined with option `AllScope`, which invariably makes them visible in *all* scopes, not just descendant ones.

**Workarounds**:

- In-process:

  - Call your script via a *thread job*, using `Start-ThreadJob` (PowerShell v6+) or with `ForEach-Object -Parallel` (v7+); e.g.:

    - `ForEach-Object -Parallel { $PSScriptRoot/child.ps1 }`
    - Thread jobs and the threads created by `ForEach-Object -Parallel` do not inherit the caller's state (with the exception of the current location in v7+)<sup>[1]</sup>.
  - At the start of your script, enumerate all variables via `Get-Variable` and create local copies that you explicitly set to `$null` (you'll need to ignore errors stemming from built-in variables that you cannot override) - this will effectively shadow the variables from ancestral scopes.
- Out-of-process:

  - Call your script via a new PowerShell process (`powershell -File ...` or `pwsh -File ...`) or via a background job (using `Start-Job`).

    - *Caveat*: In addition to decreased performance, due to cross-process XML-serialized serialization type fidelity may be lost - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] Note that providing an *opt-in* for copying the caller's state to the `ForEach-Object -Parallel` threads is now being considered; see [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12240).</sup>