# Does there exist a designated (sub)index delimiter?

Tags: .net, powershell, indexing, hashtable

**Background**

It is quite common in PowerShell to build a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable) to quickly access objects by a specific property, e.g. to base an index on the `LastName`:

```
$List =  ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Id, LastName, FirstName, Country
 1, Aerts,    Ronald,    Belgium
 2, Berg,     Ashly,     Germany
 3, Cook,     James,     England
 4, Duval,    Frank,     France
 5, Lyberg,   Ash,       England
 6, Fischer,  Adam,      Germany
'@

$Index = @{}
$List |ForEach-Object { $Index[$_.LastName] = $_ }

$Index.Cook

Id LastName FirstName Country
-- -------- --------- -------
3  Cook     James     England
```

In some cases it is required to build the index on two (or even more) properties, e.g. the `FirstName` and the `LastName`. For this you might create a multi dimensional key, e.g.:

```
$Index = @{}
$List |ForEach-Object {
     $Index[$_.FirstName] = @{}
     $Index[$_.FirstName][$_.LastName] = $_
}

$Index.James.Cook

Id LastName FirstName Country
-- -------- --------- -------
3  Cook     James     England
```

But it is easier (and possibly even faster) to just concatenate the two properties. If only for checking for the existence of the entry: `$Index.ContainsKey('James').ContainsKey('Cook')` where an error might occur if the `FirstName` doesn't exist.
To join the properties, it is required to use a delimiter between the property otherwise different property lists might end up as the same key. As this example: `AshlyBerg` and `AshLyberg`.

```
$Index = @{}
$List |ForEach-Object { $Index["$($_.FirstName)`t$($_.LastName)"] = $_ }

$Index."James`tCook"

Id LastName FirstName Country
-- -------- --------- -------
3  Cook     James     England
```

**Note:** the above are [Minimal, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In real life, I come several times to the questions below, which includes generally joining objects where the background - and number of properties used in the index are variable.

**Questions:**

1. Is it a good practice to join (concatenate) properties for such a situation?
2. If yes, is there a (standard?) delimiter for this? (meaning a character -or a sequence of characters- that should never be used/exist in a property name)

Comment: I think whether it's good practice to join the keys, depends on whether you only need to look up by full name. I've used the _unit separator_ (ASCII 0x1F) as delimiter of string fields. [List of control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_controls).

Comment: Another option is to generate a random delimiter for every table you built (much like the boundary delimiters in a multi-part email): `[string]$delim = New-Guid; $List |%{ $Index[($_.FirstName,$_.LastName-join$delim)] = $_ }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is ***no* built-in separator for multi-component hashtable (dictionary) keys**.

As for a ***custom* separator**: Your best bet for a character that is very unlikely to occur in the components themselves is **`NUL`** (the character with **code point `0x0`**), which you can represent as **`` "`0" ``** in PowerShell. However, **performing *convention-based* string operations on every lookup is awkward** (e.g. `` $Index."James`0Cook" ``) and generally **only works if *stringifying* the key components is feasible** - or if they're all strings to begin with, as in your example.

**Using *arrays* for multi-component keys is syntactically preferable, but using collections generally does *not* work as-is**, because .NET *reference types* in general do not compare distinct instances meaningfully, even if they happen to represent the same data - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69335379/45375).

- Note: The following assumes that the *elements* of collections serving as keys *do* compare meaningfully (are themselves *strings* or .NET *value types* or .NET reference types with custom equality logic). If that assumption doesn't hold, there's no robust general solution, but a best-effort approach based on CLIXML serialization shown in the linked answer may work, which you yourself have proposed.

[zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72773468/45375) uses ***tuples***, which ***do* perform meaningful comparisons** of distinct instances whose *members* contain equal data.
However, **the need to construct a tuple instance *for each addition / modification / lookup* is syntactically awkward** (e.g., 
`$Index.([Tuple]::Create('James', 'Cook'))`

**There *is* a way of making regular PowerShell *arrays* work as hastable keys**, in a manner that **only adds complexity to *creating* the hashtable** (calling a constructor), **while allowing regular array syntax for *additions / updates* and *lookups*** (e.g., `$Index.('James', 'Cook')`).

- Note: The following **works equally with `[ordered]` hashtables**, which, however, must be referred to by their true type name so as to be able to call a construct, namely [`[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary).
  However, it does *not* work with *generic* dictionaries (`[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[TKey, TValue]]`).

```bash
# Sample objects for the hashtable.
$list =  ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Id, LastName, FirstName, Country
 1, Aerts,    Ronald,    Belgium
 2, Berg,     Ashly,     Germany
 3, Cook,     James,     England
 4, Duval,    Frank,     France
 5, Lyberg,   Ash,       England
 6, Fischer,  Adam,      Germany
'@

# Initialize the hashtable with a structural equality comparer, i.e.
# a comparer that compares the *elements* of the array and only returns $true
# if *all* compare equal.
# This relies on the fact that [System.Array] implements the
# [System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] interface.
$dict = [hashtable]::new([Collections.StructuralComparisons]::StructuralEqualityComparer)

# Add entries that map the combination of first name and last name 
# to each object in $list.
# Note the regular array syntax.
$list.ForEach({ $dict.($_.FirstName, $_.LastName) = $_ })

# Use regular array syntax for lookups too.
# Note: CASE MATTERS
$dict.('James', 'Cook')
```

**Important**: The above **performs case-SENSITIVE comparisons** (as zett42's tuple solution does), unlike regular PowerShell hashtables.

**Making the comparisons case-INSENSITIVE requires more work**, because a custom implementation of the [`[System.Collections.IEqualityComparer]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEqualityComparer) interface is required, namely a case-*insensitive* implementation of what [`[System.Collections.StructuralComparisons]::StructuralEqualityComparer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer) provides:

```bash
# Case-insensitive IEqualityComparer implementation for 
# use of arrays as dictionary keys.
# Note: Dictionary keys cannot be $null, so there is no need for $null checks.
class CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer: System.Collections.IEqualityComparer {
   [bool] Equals([object] $o1, [object] $o2) {
      return ([System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] [array] $o1).Equals([array] $o2, [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
   }
   [int] GetHashCode([object] $o) {
     return ([System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] [array] $o).GetHashCode([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
   }
}

# Pass an instance of the custom equality comparer to the constructor.
$dict = [hashtable]::new([CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer]::new())
```

Note:

- [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) discovered `([System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] $o).GetHashCode([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` as a built-in way to get a hash code for an array based on its elements' case-*insensitive* hash codes.
- The original solutions below calculate the array's case-insensitive hash code  *element by element*, which is both more cumbersome and less efficient. Perhaps they are still of interest in general with respect to how hash codes are calculated.

---

#### Optional reading: element-by-element hash-code implementations:

```bash
# Case-insensitive IEqualityComparer implementation for arrays.
# See the bottom section of this answer for a better .NET 7+ alternative.
class CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer: System.Collections.IEqualityComparer {
  [bool] Equals([object] $o1, [object] $o2) {
    return ([System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] [array] $o1).Equals([array] $o2, [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
  }
  [int] GetHashCode([object] $o) {
    if ($o -isnot [Array]) { return $o.GetHashCode() }
    [int] $hashCode = 0
    foreach ($el in $o) {
      if ($null -eq $el) { 
        continue
      } elseif ($el -is [string]) {
        $hashCode = $hashCode -bxor $el.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode()
      } else {
        $hashCode = $hashCode -bxor $el.GetHashCode()
      }
    }
    return $hashCode
  }
}

$list =  ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Id, LastName, FirstName, Country
 1, Aerts,    Ronald,    Belgium
 2, Berg,     Ashly,     Germany
 3, Cook,     James,     England
 4, Duval,    Frank,     France
 5, Lyberg,   Ash,       England
 6, Fischer,  Adam,      Germany
'@

# Pass an instance of the custom equality comparer to the constructor.
$dict = [hashtable]::new([CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer]::new())

$list.ForEach({ $dict.($_.FirstName, $_.LastName) = $_ })

# Now, case does NOT matter.
$dict.('james', 'cook')
```

---

A note on the **`.GetHashCode()` implementation** in the custom comparer class above:

- A custom [`.GetHashCode()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object.GetHashCode) implementation is required to return the *same* hash code (an `[int]` value) for all objects that compare as equal (that is, if `$o1 -eq $o2` is `$true`, `$o1.GetHashCode()` and `$o2.GetHashCode()` must return the same value).
- While hash codes aren't required to be *unique* (and cannot be in all cases), ideally as few objects as possible share the same hash code, as that reduces the number of so-called collisions, which decreases the lookup efficiency of hash tables - see the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for background information.
- The implementation above uses a fairly simple, [`-bxor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators)-based (bitwise XOR) algorithm, which results in the same hash code for two arrays that have the same elements, but in *different order*.

  - The [`.GetHashCode()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object.GetHashCode) help topic shows more sophisticated approaches, including using an *auxiliary* tuple instance, as *its* hash code algorithm is order-aware - while simple, this approach is computationally expensive, and more work is needed for better performance. See the bottom section for a .NET 7+ option.

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42)'s **collision test code** (adapted), which determines how many among 1000 arrays with a given number of elements that are random string values result in the *same* hash code, i.e. produce collisions, and calculates a collision percentage from that. If you need to improve the efficiency of the implementation above you can use this code to test it (possibly also to measure the tests' *runtime* to see how different implementations compare).

```bash
# Create an instance of the custom comparer defined above.
$cmp = [CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer]::new()

$numArrays = 1000
foreach ($elementCount in 2..5 + 10) {

  $numUniqueHashes = (
      1..$numArrays | 
      ForEach-Object { 
        $cmp.GetHashCode(@(1..$elementCount | ForEach-Object { "$(New-Guid)" })) 
      } |
      Sort-Object -Unique
    ).Count

  [pscustomobject] @{
    ElementCount = $elementCount
    CollisionPercentage = '{0:P2}' -f (($numArrays - $numUniqueHashes) / $numArrays)
  }

}
```

The about outputs 0% for all tests, so it seems that the `-bxor` approach is sufficient to prevent collisions, at least with random strings and without including variations of arrays that differ in element *order* only.
Read on for a superior .NET 7+ solution.

---

**Superior custom equality comparer implementation in .NET 7+** (requires at least a preview version of PowerShell 7.3):

zett42 points out that [`[HashCode]::Combine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.HashCode.Combine), available in .NET 7+, allows for a more efficient implementation, as it:

- is *order-aware*
- allows determining a hash code for *multiple* values in a *single operation*.

Note:

- The method is limited to ***at most `8`* array elements** - but for multi-component that should be enough.
- The values to combine - the array elements in this case - must be passed as *individual arguments* to the methods - passing the array *as a whole* doesn't work as intended. This makes the implementation somewhat cumbersome.

```bash
# .NET 7+ / PowerShell 7.3+
# Case-insensitive IEqualityComparer implementation for arrays
# using [HashCode]::Combine() - limited to 8 elements.
class CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer: System.Collections.IEqualityComparer {
  [bool] Equals([object] $o1, [object] $o2) {
    return ([System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] [array] $o1).Equals([array] $o2, [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
  }
  [int] GetHashCode([object] $o) {
    if ($o -isnot [Array] -or 0 -eq $o.Count) { return $o.GetHashCode() }
    $o = $o.ForEach({ $_ -is [string] ? $_.ToLowerInvariant() : $_ })
    $hashCode = switch ($o.Count) {
      1 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0]) }
      2 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0], $o[1]) }
      3 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0], $o[1], $o[2]) }
      4 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0], $o[1], $o[2], $o[3]) }
      5 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0], $o[1], $o[2], $o[3], $o[4]) }
      6 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0], $o[1], $o[2], $o[3], $o[4], $o[5]) }
      7 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0], $o[1], $o[2], $o[3], $o[4], $o[5], $o[6]) }
      8 { [HashCode]::Combine($o[0], $o[1], $o[2], $o[3], $o[4], $o[5], $o[6], $o[7]) }
      default { throw 'Not implemented for more than 8 array elements.' }
    }
    return $hashCode
  }
}
```

However, as zett42 points out, **you can overcame the value-count limit  by calling `[HashCode]::Combine()` *iteratively*, in a loop**.

**In the case of a case-*insensitive* implementation**, that isn't too much overhead, given that **you need a loop anyway**, namely in order to call `.ToLowerInvariant()` on `[string]`-typed values (which is what the `.ForEach()` call above implicitly does).

Here is his implementation:

```bash
# .NET 7+ / PowerShell 7.3+
# Case-insensitive IEqualityComparer implementation for arrays
# using [HashCode]::Combine() *iteratively*, with *no* element-count limit.
class CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer: System.Collections.IEqualityComparer {
  [bool] Equals([object] $o1, [object] $o2) {
    return ([System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] [array] $o1).Equals([array] $o2, [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
  }
  [int] GetHashCode([object] $o) {
    if ($o -isnot [Array] -or 0 -eq $o.Count) { return $o.GetHashCode() }
    
    $hashCode = 0
    $o.ForEach({ 
        $value = $_ -is [string] ? $_.ToLowerInvariant() : $_
        $hashCode = [HashCode]::Combine( $hashCode, $value )
    })

    return $hashCode
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @zett42 - I actually meant to use `-bxor` to begin with - `-bor` performs much worse. In fact, `-bxor` seems to make all collisions go away in your test. Please see my update, and let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @zett42 -the tests are still good to have in general (sanity check, measuring runtime to see how _fast_ the implementation is, ...). Thanks for the tip re `[HashCode]::Combine()` - I've added a bottom section to the answer that show its use and notes its limitations.

Comment: Suggestion to remove the limitation of max. 8 array elements: https://gist.github.com/zett42/7e18b3fa9cd6614ad6e5e4ce13dad156 . Haven't tested performance yet.

Comment: For 8 elements, yours is faster by a factor of about `1.4`.  I guess the method call overhead is significant for the looped version. https://gist.github.com/zett42/ec8c6eaaf333001b5f8e5358d6aca563

Comment: Thanks, @zett42 - please see my update. The biggest gain from a _single_ `[HashCode]::Combine()` call comes if you don't also have to loop over the array for a different reason, such as for case-insensitivity here.

Comment: The performance gain of the C# version ([`CaseInsensitiveArrayEqualityComparer3`](https://gist.github.com/zett42/ec8c6eaaf333001b5f8e5358d6aca563)) is pretty impressive. On my machine, it runs about 10x faster than the PowerShell switch-based version. Let me know what you think about the code. I tried to make it more generic by testing for the implemented interfaces instead of explicit `Array` type checking.

Comment: @zett42, https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17614 may be of interest: when I looked at your C# code, I noticed the `new` to , and tried to avoid with an _explicit_ interface implementation - only to find that PowerShell then can't find the `.Equals()` method except with an interface cast.

Comment: Love this answer, already had it upvoted, but after some research I'm wondering why didn't you use `([IStructuralEquatable] $o).GetHashCode([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` ?

Comment: Thanks, @Santiago. The answer is simple: Because I didn't know about it :) Nice job. Please see my update.

Comment: my pleasure ;) `IStructuralEquatable` is indeed an awesome interface

Comment: Have been tinkering a bit with this interface, decided to test it for a [function to get unique values from objects](https://github.com/santysq/Select-Unique) and compared with `Sort-Object -Unique` the results are pretty Ok. And also a class to [compare `PSCustomObjects`](https://gist.github.com/santysq/4c84c1d7904dfb14421d589b22d29a90). If you see any room for improvements and / or are willing to review them it would be much appreciated

Comment: Thanks, @Santiago, I'll take a look. Quick note: re `Select-Unique`: it is actually more similar to `Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: It is, but `Select-Object` can do it on one property only while `Sort-Object` can work on multiple properties.

Comment: For manually hashing I was attempting to replicate [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/15339544) used by Jon Skeet in C# but unfortunately we don't have the `unchecked` statement in pwsh, not sure how or if there is a why it could be replicated

Comment: @Santiago. Unfortunately, it's both complicated and slow to replicate `unchecked` behavior in PowerShell, at least to my knowledge. The only way I've found is via hex _string_ representations; e.g.: `[int] ('0x' + ([long]::MaxValue.ToString('x') -replace '^.*(?=.{8}$)')) # -> -1`. I've created a `ConvertTo-IntegerUnchecked` function in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/a700e598b615a1d432cc87e7291cdfec) that generalizes the technique, though, given the poor performance, it is probably mostly of interest as an educational tool.  `-Verbose` shows what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Good point, @iRon, thanks. Please see my update, which uses `[array]` rather than `@(...)` for efficiency, however (though that may not matter in practice).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** While the following solution works, it isn't nearly as clean as the [solution provided by mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72793529/7571258), which I recommend to use. Tuples can be useful in many other situations, so I'll keep this answer as an example.

---

Instead of joining the keys I suggest to use a "split key" by the help of the [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=net-6.0) class. In this case there is no need for a delimiter, as the keys are not joined but stored as **separate properties** in an object. The `Tuple` class provides the necessary interfaces so the tuple acts like a single key when used in any `Dictionary` (e. g. `Hashtable`).

```sh
$List =  ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Id, LastName, FirstName, Country
 1, Aerts,    Ronald,    Belgium
 2, Berg,     Ashly,     Germany
 3, Cook,     James,     England
 4, Duval,    Frank,     France
 5, Lyberg,   Ash,       England
 6, Fischer,  Adam,      Germany
'@

$Index = @{}
$List.ForEach{ $Index[ [Tuple]::Create( $_.LastName, $_.FirstName ) ] = $_ }

$Index
```

When written to the console, the split key gets nicely formatted:

```text
Name                           Value
----                           -----
(Berg, Ashly)                  @{Id=2; LastName=Berg; FirstName=Ashly; Country=Germany}
(Lyberg, Ash)                  @{Id=5; LastName=Lyberg; FirstName=Ash; Country=England}
(Duval, Frank)                 @{Id=4; LastName=Duval; FirstName=Frank; Country=France}
(Aerts, Ronald)                @{Id=1; LastName=Aerts; FirstName=Ronald; Country=Belgium}
(Cook, James)                  @{Id=3; LastName=Cook; FirstName=James; Country=England}
(Fischer, Adam)                @{Id=6; LastName=Fischer; FirstName=Adam; Country=Germany}
```

To look up an entry, create a temporary tuple:

```
$Index[ [Tuple]::Create('Duval','Frank') ]
```

An advantage of the `Tuple` class is that you can easily get the individual keys that make up the split key, without having to split a string:

```
# Using member access enumeration
$Index.Keys.Item1  # Prints all last names
$Index.Keys.Item2  # Prints all first names

# Using the enumerator to loop over the index
$Index.GetEnumerator().ForEach{ $_.Key.Item1 }
```

---

The .NET Framework 4.7 adds the [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-6.0) *struct* ([what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple)). It might be worth testing whether it gives better **performance** for this use case. Also, replacing `Hashtable` by a generic `Dictionary` could improve performance as well:

```sh
$Index = [Collections.Generic.Dictionary[ ValueTuple[String,String], object]]::new()
```

Apart from construction of the dictionary, `ValueTuple` can be used like `Tuple`. Simply replace `Tuple` by `ValueTuple` in the previous code samples.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, an `ArrayEqualityComparer` that (optionally) supports `MatchCase` and `StrictMode`:

```
class ArrayEqualityComparer: System.Collections.IEqualityComparer {
    [bool]$MatchCase
    [bool]$Strict
    [bool]Equals($Object1, $Object2) {
        $Array1 = [System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] [array] $Object1
        $Array2 = [System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable] [array] $Object2
        $Count = $Array1.get_Count()
        if ($Count -ne $Array2.get_Count()) { return $False }
        else {
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Count; $i++) {
                if ( $Null -ne $Array1[$i] -and $Null -ne $Array2[$i] ) {
                    if ($This.Strict -and $Array1[$i].GetType() -ne $Array2[$i].GetType()) { return $False }
                    if ($This.MatchCase) { if ($Array1[$i] -cne $Array2[$i]) { return $False } }
                    elseif ($Array1[$i] -ne $Array2[$i]) { return $False }
                } elseif ( $Null -eq $Array1[$i] -or $Null -eq $Array2[$i] ) { return $False }
            }
        }
        return $True
    }
    [int]GetHashCode($Object) {
        [int]$HashCode = 0
        foreach ($Item in $Object) {
            if ($Null -ne $Item) {
                if ($Item -is [String]) { if (!$This.MatchCase) { $Item = $Item.ToLowerInvariant() } }
                elseif (!$This.Strict) { $Item = "$Item" }
                $HashCode = $HashCode -bXor $Item.GetHashCode()
            }
        }
        return $HashCode
    }
    ArrayEqualityComparer() {}
    ArrayEqualityComparer( [bool]$MatchCase ) { $This.MatchCase = $MatchCase }
    ArrayEqualityComparer( [bool]$MatchCase, [bool] $Strict ) { $This.MatchCase = $MatchCase; $This.Strict = $Strict }
}
```

**(Pester) Tests:**

```
Describe 'ArrayEqualityComparer' {

    Context 'Loose, Case Insensitive' {

        BeforeAll {
            $Comparer = [ArrayEqualityComparer]::new()
            $Hashtable = [hashtable]::new($Comparer)
            $Hashtable['abc'] = 1
            $Hashtable[('def', '123')] = 2
            $Hashtable[('ghi', '456', 'jkl')] = 3
        }

        It 'Contains' {
            $Hashtable.Contains('abc')                 |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', '123'))        |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', '123'))        |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', 123))          |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', 123))          |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('ghi', '456', 'jkl')) |Should -BeTrue
        }

        It 'Value' {
            $Hashtable.'abc'                 |Should -Be 1
            $Hashtable.('def', '123')        |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('DEF', '123')        |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('def', 123)          |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('DEF', 123)          |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('ghi', '456', 'jkl') |Should -Be 3
        }
    }

    Context 'Loose, Case Sensitive' {

        BeforeAll {
            $Comparer = [ArrayEqualityComparer]::new($True)
            $Hashtable = [hashtable]::new($Comparer)
            $Hashtable['abc'] = 1
            $Hashtable[('def', '123')] = 2
            $Hashtable[('ghi', '456', 'jkl')] = 3
        }

        It 'Contains' {
            $Hashtable.Contains('abc')                 |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', '123'))        |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', '123'))        |Should -BeFalse
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', 123))          |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', 123))          |Should -BeFalse
            $Hashtable.Contains(('ghi', '456', 'jkl')) |Should -BeTrue
        }

        It 'Value' {
            $Hashtable.'abc'                 |Should -Be 1
            $Hashtable.('def', '123')        |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('DEF', '123')        |Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            $Hashtable.('def', 123)          |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('DEF', 123)          |Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            $Hashtable.('ghi', '456', 'jkl') |Should -Be 3
        }
    }

    Context 'Strict, Case Insensitive' {

        BeforeAll {
            $Comparer = [ArrayEqualityComparer]::new($False, $True)
            $Hashtable = [hashtable]::new($Comparer)
            $Hashtable['abc'] = 1
            $Hashtable[('def', '123')] = 2
            $Hashtable[('ghi', '456', 'jkl')] = 3
        }

        It 'Contains' {
            $Hashtable.Contains('abc')                 |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', '123'))        |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', '123'))        |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', 123))          |Should -BeFalse
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', 123))          |Should -BeFalse
            $Hashtable.Contains(('ghi', '456', 'jkl')) |Should -BeTrue
        }

        It 'Value' {
            $Hashtable.'abc' |Should -Be 1
            $Hashtable.('def', '123')        |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('DEF', '123')        |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('def', 123)          |Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            $Hashtable.('DEF', 123)          |Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            $Hashtable.('ghi', '456', 'jkl') |Should -Be 3
        }
    }

    Context 'Strict, Case Sensitive' {

        BeforeAll {
            $Comparer = [ArrayEqualityComparer]::new($True, $True)
            $Hashtable = [hashtable]::new($Comparer)
            $Hashtable['abc'] = 1
            $Hashtable[('def', '123')] = 2
            $Hashtable[('ghi', '456', 'jkl')] = 3
        }

        It 'Contains' {
            $Hashtable.Contains('abc')                 |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', '123'))        |Should -BeTrue
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', '123'))        |Should -BeFalse
            $Hashtable.Contains(('def', 123))          |Should -BeFalse
            $Hashtable.Contains(('DEF', 123))          |Should -BeFalse
            $Hashtable.Contains(('ghi', '456', 'jkl')) |Should -BeTrue
        }

        It 'Value' {
            $Hashtable.'abc'                 |Should -Be 1
            $Hashtable.('def', '123')        |Should -Be 2
            $Hashtable.('DEF', '123')        |Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            $Hashtable.('def', 123)          |Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            $Hashtable.('DEF', 123)          |Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            $Hashtable.('ghi', '456', 'jkl') |Should -Be 3
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is about 20% slower than join the keys with a delimiter