# Powershell Add-Members Dynamically

Tags: powershell

Long story short - it seems impossible to get a pipeline value to resolve to plain text in a `ScriptProperty` and so I'm looking for a way to either do that, or to somehow parameterize when I'm adding properties to an object. I would be perfectly happy to add the values as `NotePropertyMembers` rather than a `ScriptProperty`; but I can't find a way to do that without looping through the entire object multiple times. The advantage of the `ScriptProperty` is the ability to use the `$this` variable so that I don't need to call `Add-Member` on each member of the object itself.

Here's what an example of what I'm trying to accomplish and where it is breaking down.

```
# This sample file contains the values that I'm interested in
@'
ID,CATEGORY,AVERAGE,MEDIAN,MIN,MAX
100,"",52,50,10,100
100,1,40,40,20,60
100,2,41,35,15,85
'@ > values.csv

# To access the values, I decided to create a HashTable
$map = @{}
(Import-Csv values.csv).ForEach({$map[$_.ID + $_.CATEGORY] = $_})

# This is my original object. In reality, it has several additional columns of data - but it is
# missing the above values which is why I want to pull them in
@'
ID,CATEGORY
100,""
100,1
100,2
'@ > object.csv

$object = Import-Csv object.csv

# This is the meat of my attempt. Loop through all of the properties in the HashTable that
# I need to pull into my object and add them
$map.Values | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotIn 'ID', 'CATEGORY'} | ForEach-Object {$object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "$($_.Name)" -Value {$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."$($_.Name)"}}
```

In theory, I know that it works because I can display the values for a particular member of my object using the code below

```
$map.Values | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotIn 'ID', 'CATEGORY'} | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Name) = " + $map[$object[0].ID + $object[0].CATEGORY]."$($_.Name)"}
```

Displays

```
AVERAGE = 52
MAX = 100
MEDIAN = 50
MIN = 10
```

However - it is clear that `$_.Name` and `"$($_.Name)"` do not resolve to their plain text description when they're in the `ScriptProperty`

```
PS> $object | GM -MemberType ScriptProperty

# Displays
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name    MemberType     Definition
----    ----------     ----------
AVERAGE ScriptProperty System.Object AVERAGE {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."$($_.Name)";}
MAX     ScriptProperty System.Object MAX {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."$($_.Name)";}
MEDIAN  ScriptProperty System.Object MEDIAN {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."$($_.Name)";}
MIN     ScriptProperty System.Object MIN {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."$($_.Name)";}
```

To me, an obvious workaround is to individually add each column which still allows me to take advantage of using `Add-Member` on the object itself instead of each individual member. However, the entire idea is to be able to dynamically add values without knowing ahead of time what their names are - in order to do that, I need to find a way to force the name to resolve within the `ScriptProperty`

```
# Workaround for this incredibly simple example
PS> $object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name AVERAGE -Value {$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."AVERAGE"}
PS> $object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name MEDIAN -Value {$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."MEDIAN"}
PS> $object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name MIN -Value {$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."MIN"}
PS> $object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name MAX -Value {$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."MAX"}

PS> $object | GM -MemberType ScriptProperty

# Displays

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name    MemberType     Definition
----    ----------     ----------
AVERAGE ScriptProperty System.Object AVERAGE {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."AVERAGE";}
MAX     ScriptProperty System.Object MAX {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."MAX";}
MEDIAN  ScriptProperty System.Object MEDIAN {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."MEDIAN";}
MIN     ScriptProperty System.Object MIN {get=$map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY]."MIN";}
```

Comment: The end result is a merge of `values.csv` and `object.csv` having the same `ID` + `CATEGORY` property values ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - precisely

Comment: Not if understand the hassle with the `ScriptProperty`,, so far I can tell, your question effectively comes down to this question: [In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848821/1701026) (or any of the related ones in my answer). Using the [Join-Script](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object) from my answer: `Import-Csv object.csv |Update-Object (Import-Csv values.csv) -on ID,CATEGORY`.

Comment: Be aware that there is even a pitfall in your approach where two different ID,CATEGORY might resolve in the same key (e.g. `12,1` and  `1,21`). See: [Does there exist a designated (sub)index delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72772327/1701026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementing the helpful [answer from Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73502823/15339544) which creates new objects, here is how you can approach dynamically updating the object itself:

```
$exclude = 'ID', 'CATEGORY'
$map = @{}
$properties = $values[0].PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object { $_ -notin $exclude }
$values.ForEach{ $map[$_.ID + $_.CATEGORY] = $_ | Select-Object $properties }

foreach($line in $object) {
    $newValues = $map[$line.ID + $line.CATEGORY]
    foreach($property in $properties) {
        $line.PSObject.Properties.Add(
            [psnoteproperty]::new($property, $newValues.$property)
        )
    }
}
```

Above code assumes that both Csvs (`$values` and `$object`) are loaded in memory and that you know which properties from the `$values` Csv should be excluded.

Comment: Perfect! I think this is the route I was thinking in terms of looping through `$object`, but the nested `ForEach` is what I was missing so that I didn't need to loop through the entire thing multiple times!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select-Object` instead of `Add-Member`:

```
$object |Select *,@{Name='Average';Expression={$map[$_.ID + $_.Category].Average}},@{Name='Median';Expression={$map[$_.ID + $_.Category].Median}},@{Name='Min';Expression={$map[$_.ID + $_.Category].Min}},@{Name='Max';Expression={$map[$_.ID + $_.Category].Max}}
```

`Select-Object` will evaluate the `Expression` block against every single individual input item, thereby resolving the mapping immediately, as opposed to deferring it until someone references the property

Comment: Issue with this method, aside from the fact that I initially planned to defer evaluation until using `Export-Csv`, is that it seems like you'd need to know the names of every new property you're selecting. The original goal was to loop through the `NoteProperty` members of $values and all of them without necessarily knowing their names or even the total count

Comment: @immobile2 I must be missing something here? - if you want to recreate the objects in `$values` then all you need is `$valuesCopied = $values |Select *`

Comment: My `$object` has more columns than just the ID and Category, for the sake of simplicity I just didn't add all of those. So the goal is to merge the columns from `$values` into `$object` keeping all of the original columns contained in `$object`

Answer (score 2):

One additional option that I stumbled upon while working with [Santiago's great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73503106/15243610). Using `Add-Member` rather than the `Properties.Add()` method would allow for a hash table of `NotePropertyMembers` to used, which could be advantageous although I haven't started testing performance of different methods yet. It makes things a bit simpler if you already have a hash table of the properties and values that you want to add to your object.

```
$map = @{}

# This will create a hash table nested in the hash table, rather than a hash table whose values are PSCustomObjects
$values.ForEach{$map[$_.ID + $_.CATEGORY] = $_.PSObject.Properties | ?{$_.Name -notin $exclude} | % {$ht = @{}} {$ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value} {$ht}}

ForEach($line in $object){
    If($map.Contains($line.ID + $line.CATEGORY){
        $line | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $map[$line.ID + $line.CATEGORY]
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point to reduce the code but note, what `Add-Member` is doing behind the scenes is very similar to what my code does :)

Comment: Agreed - and it is definitely nice to see them both. The ability to add a hash table in one swoop is potentially helpful for others, but based on some testing I've done with the files I was working with, it looks like your method outperforms the overhead of calling `Add-Member` and also throws fewer errors in instances where the lookup value doesn't exist as a key in the hash table (throwing errors may be better, TBD!)

Answer (score 2):

**[Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73503106/45375)** and **[your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504621/45375)**, based on **static `NoteProperty` members** rather than the originally requested dynamic `ScriptProperty` members, turned out to be the **better solution** in the case at hand.

---

As for **how you could have made your *dynamic* `ScriptProperty` approach work**:

```bash
$map.Values | 
  Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | 
  Where-Object Name -NotIn ID, CATEGORY | 
  ForEach-Object {
    # Cache the property name at hand, so it can be referred to
    # in the pipeline below.
    $propName = $_.Name
    # .GetNewClosure() is necessary for capturing the value of $amp
    # as well as the current value of $propName as part of the script block.
    $object |
      Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty `
                 -Name $propName `
                 -Value { $map[$this.ID + $this.CATEGORY].$propName }.GetNewClosure()
  }
```

Note that use of [`.GetNewClosure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure) is crucial, so as to *capture*:

- *each iteration's* then-current `$propName` variable value
- the `$map` variable's hashtable

as part of the script block.

Note:

- `.GetNewClosure()` is expensive, as it creates a dynamic module behind the scenes in which the captured values are cached and to which the script block gets bound.
- Generally, it's better to restrict `ScriptProperty` members to calculations that are *self-contained*, i.e. rely only on the state of the object itself (accessible via [automatic `$this` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this)), not also on outside values; a simple example:

  ```bash
  $o = [pscustomobject] @{ A = 1; B = 2}
  $o | Add-Member -Type ScriptProperty -Name C { $this.A + $this.B }
  $o.C # -> 3
  $o.A = 2; $o.C # -> 4
  ```