# String interpolation in PowerShell for hashmaps

Tags: string, powershell, string-interpolation

I have a list of hashmaps. I want to create comma separated string for each item. If I use the following, it works fine.

```
$users | ForEach-Object {$_.firstname + "," + $_.surname}
```

But when I try to do it with string interpolation like this,

```
$users | ForEach-Object {"$_.firstname,$_.surname"}
```

It shows

```
System.Collections.Hashtable.firstname,System.Collections.Hashtable.surname
```

What mistake am I doing?

Comment: Answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145704/how-can-you-use-an-objects-property-in-a-double-quoted-string // use `"$(....)"` for string interpolation

Comment: You might also have a look in here: [Does there exist a designated (sub)index delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72793529/1701026)