# Powershell scripting : Why is this function not able to access a global variable

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

i have a script, let's say script1 that calls a function abc from script2.
Below is script2 :-

```
$Global:splat2 
function xyz ()
{
    Write-Host "in xyz"
    Write-Host "$Global:splat2"
}
function abc ([System.Collections.ArrayList] $splat)
{
    $Global:splat2 = $splat
    Write-Host "in abc"
    Write-Host "$Global:splat2"
    $func = (Get-Command -Type Function xyz)
    $wholeFuncDef = 'Function ' + $func.Name + " {`n" + $func.Definition + "`n}"

    Start-Process powershell -args '-noprofile', '-noexit', '-EncodedCommand', `([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("$wholeFuncDef; xyz")))
    
}
```

The function abc is called from script 1 (some value was assigned to $splat):

```
abc $splat
```

The problem is that only function abc prints the value for $splat2 while as in function xyz, $splat2 is empty.
I was expecting that function xyz should also have the value for $splat2 since it's a global variable.

Comment: Looking at this, I see nothing wrong, nor can I replicate this issue on PS 5.1. What PowerShell version are you using btw?

Comment: sorry, i have edited the question now. Actuallly the function xyz is being called in a separate console

Comment: By separate console, do you mean by a different conhost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global variables are limited to a given *session*, i.e. a PowerShell runspace (thread) inside a given process.

Using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with `powershell.exe` invariably creates a *new* session, in a *new process*, which knows nothing about the caller's variables (except for inheriting *environment* variables by default).

---

You'll have to pass any values from the caller's scope *explicitly* to such a separate session.

Options:

- Incorporate values from the caller's scope as a variable-assignment  statements into the (Base64-encoded) command string passed to `-EncodedCommand`
- A simple alternative is indeed to use an aux. *environment* variable.

Caveat re data types:

- If you use an environment variable, its value is invariably a *string*.
- If you incorporate a variable assignment into the command string, you can express more data types, but are limited to those that can be expressed as *literals* in PowerShell (unless you include a constructor call based on a literal, if feasible).
- Supporting *more* data types - but not *all* - is possible with the - undocumented as of this writing - `-EncodedArguments` parameter; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).