# How to preserve the "Name" and "BaseType" of PowerShell Variables for System.* BaseTypes

Tags: powershell, encryption

Most Power Shell variables are a "String, char Object[] array, or Byte[] array". Example:

```
$string = "hello world"
$string.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

# OR
$char = 1,2,3,4,5,6
$char.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

But doing things like Encryption with Power Shell such as RSA returns the Base Type of

```
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    RSACryptoServiceProvider                 System.Security.Cryptography.RSA
```

Trying to extract or save the "System.Security.Cryptography.RSA" $rsa BaseType and restore it from a variable breaks the Base Type. Only way that seems to work is to export the $rsa to a xml file and import it later as

```
Export-Clixml -InputObject $rsa -Path .\rsa.xml
$imported_rsa = Import-Clixml -Path ".\rsa.xml"
```

However you can't do it with a variable if the rsa.xml is stored as a string. Getting this error.

```
$xml_string = @"
<xml-data>
"@

$xml_string.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

$imported_rsa = Import-Clixml $xml_string
Import-Clixml: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http' does not exist.
```

Doing it with PSSerializer looks correct but is converted to the wrong type of System.Object

```
$rsa

CspKeyContainerInfo  : 
KeyExchangeAlgorithm : RSA
KeySize              : 1024
LegalKeySizes        : {System.Security.Cryptography.KeySizes}
PersistKeyInCsp      : False
PublicOnly           : False
SignatureAlgorithm   : http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

$rsa.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    RSACryptoServiceProvider                 System.Security.Cryptography.RSA

$xml_string = @"
<xml-data>
"@

[Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($xml_string)

KeyExchangeAlgorithm : RSA
KeySize              : 1024
LegalKeySizes        : {System.Security.Cryptography.KeySizes}
PersistKeyInCsp      : False
PublicOnly           : False
SignatureAlgorithm   : http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

[Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($xml_string).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     PSObject                                 System.Object
```

Attempting to save System.Security.Cryptography.RSA BaseType by converting it to a format that can be move around. Breaks once you try to move it back its System.Security.Cryptography.RSA BaseType. The only thing that seems to work is to export the $rsa variable as a XML file and Import it. However try to do it completely by storing data in variables which leads to the wrong GetType. Breaking the $rsa and not able to decrypt or encrypt anything after the fact.

Comment: `Import-CliXml` and `Export-CliXml` uses `PSSerializer` and both output `PSObject` as type when deserialized. Not all objects can be serialized and deserialized into the same object they were before serialization. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_output?view=powershell-7.2#deserialized-objects

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you explain the broader picture? The "why" is mising here.

Comment: Thant would explain why trying to export and Import just the $rsa.Decrypt part looking at the type looks weird. However exporting the whole thing to a file and importing it seems to work best.

`
$rsa.Decrypt.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name  BaseType
-------- -------- ---- --------
False    False    PSMethod1                               System.Management.Automation.PSMethod

 $dec_only.GetType()    

IsPublic IsSerial Name                  BaseType
-------- -------- ----  --------
True     True     PSObject              System.Object
`

Comment: Attempt to archive the encryption $rsa object that is created and or just the decryption part if I wanted to pass it over to another machine or script. That isn't apart of the one that encrypted it.

Comment: I really dont understand what you're trying to achieve, I agree with zett42's comment. Why do you want to serialize the object? You only need the keys afaik and those can be serialized. Then you can instantiate a new object anywhere using those keys

Comment: trying to just past over the $rsa or $rsa.Decrypt part

`$rsa=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider`
`$plaintext=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("hi")`
`$ciphertext=$rsa.Encrypt($plaintext, $false)`
`Export-Clixml -InputObject $rsa -Path .\xml.xml`
`$passed_rsa=Import-Clixml -Path .\xml.xml`
`$encode_text=$passed_rsa.Decrypt($ciphertext, $false)`
`$clear_text=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($encoded_text);$clear_text`

But without having to save the $rsa to a xml file. Kinda like
`$decrypt=<var>`
`$encoded_test=$decrypt($ciphertext, $false)`

Comment: Again, you dont need to serialize the object. You just only need to serialize the private key. Then you can create a new object and import that private key which would allow you to deserialize the `$ciphertext`. I can post an example of what I mean if that can help you

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? https://gist.github.com/santisq/a351df6384324f9a6e4e9a5427977c2b#file-testrsa-ps1

Answer (score 1):

The **`BaseType` property value** in the output from a `.GetType()` call is **the type that the input type is *derived* from**, i.e. its *immediate ancestor* in the .NET *inheritance hierarchy*.

You can easily show the entire hierarchy, starting with the input object's own time and eventually ending in `System.Object`, the root type of *all* .NET types - via the [intrinsic `pstypenames` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#pstypenames);<sup>[1]</sup> e.g.:

```bash
# [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::new() is PSv5+
# shorthand for: New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
[System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::new().pstypenames
```

Output:

```bash
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.RSA
System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm
System.Object
```

Given this relationship, there's **usually no need to *convert* a given object to any of its base types, because it *is* an instance of these types** (just of a *more specialized* (derived) kind), which you can verify with `-is`, the [type(-inheritance) / interface test operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators):

```bash
$instance = [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::new()
# -> $true
$instance -is [System.Security.Cryptography.RSA]
```

---

*Serializing*  and later deserializing objects (whether via [`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml) or directly via [`[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer)), using PowerShell's XML-based CLIXML format, is an entirely *separate issue*, and, as noted in the comments:

- Except for a few *well-known types*, deserialization results in method-less *emulations* of the original objects and their properties, using PowerShell's "property-bag" type, `[psobject]` / `[pscustomobject]`; that is, the original type identity is *lost* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] Note that it is possible for this property to  contain *virtual* entries inserted for the benefit of PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763).</sup>

Comment: Avoiding the use of Export-Clixml with trying to store the $rsa
`[System.Security.Cryptography.RSA]` in a base64 enocded string also breaks it.

`$instance = [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::new();`
`$base = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($instance));`
`$i_rsa = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($base));`
`$i_rsa;`
`$i_rsa.GetTyype;`
`$i_rsa -is [System.Security.Cryptography.RSA];`

output:
`System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider`
`False`

Comment: @IO_ASCII, you cannot meaningfully serialize an arbitrary .NET instance with `[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($instance))`. This implicitly calls `.ToString()` on `$instance`, which in many cases - including this one - simply reports the _type name_, not a meaningful representation of the instance; try `[System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::new().ToString()`