# Can I pass parameters while calling PS7 from PS?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I have a module that was written in PS5, and I'm adding a new function that requires PS7. I want to be able to run the function from PS5, so I'm thinking I can just have the function call `pwsh`, but I need to be able to pass the function parameters into the `pwsh` script block. Is this possible?

```
function Test-PS7 {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$String
    )

    pwsh {
        Write-Host $String
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you planning to constantly re-use this function in the same session?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes

Comment: then i would recommend to use a named pipe instead of invoking a new process per function call...

Comment: this is what i meant by using a named pipe: https://gist.github.com/santisq/93fd0f5a4ff9be5c542d1cbceb50aed0#file-invokepwsh7pseudomodule-psm1 too long to share it in an answer, this way you only invoke the process once and can re-use it as many times as a you want. the downside is that you must remember to call `Clear-Pipe` function or `Remove-Module` when you're done using it otherwise you will end up with hidden `pwsh` process

Comment: why don't you just execute PS7 directly from the start?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I appreciate you putting that together, I think it might be too complicated for my use though

Comment: Understandable which is why I decided to not post an answer showcasing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you **call [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, with a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)** - which is only supported when calling *from a PowerShell session* - you **can only pass *positional* arguments** to that script block, using the **`-args`** parameter (the same limitation applies to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI).

However, **you can *indirectly* support passing *named* arguments by passing the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) as a single, positional argument**, and use **[*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)** inside the script block to pass its value through to the target command.

The following demonstrates this via parameters that can be passed through to the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet, `-LiteralPath` and `-File`, as an example:

```bash
function Test-PS7 {
  param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory)]
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
      [string] $LiteralPath,
      [switch] $File
  )

  pwsh {
    param($boundParameters)

    # Compensate for the problem of [switch] parameters not
    # deserializing as such and splatting of [switch] parameters
    # requiring *[bool]* values.
    foreach ($key in @($boundParameters.Keys)) {
      if ($boundParameters[$key].pstypenames -contains 'Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter') {
        $boundParameters[$key] = $entry.IsPresent
      }
    }

    # Now @boundParameters can be used for splatting
    Get-ChildItem @boundParameters

  } -args $PSBoundParameters

}
```

Note:

- To avoid potentially unnecessary overhead and to make for a more predictable execution environment, consider adding `-NoProfile` to the `pwsh` call.
- Due to the limited type fidelity that cross-process serialization invariably entails (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375)), `[switch]` parameter turn into *emulations* which splatting doesn't recognize, necessitating the workaround above:

  - Specifically, these emulations are `[pscustomobject]` (aka `[psobject]`) instances containing copies of the original object's properties (but not *methods*), and are assigned an [ETS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) type name of `Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter`, accessible via the [intrinsic `pstypenames` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members#type-information)
  - Therefore, the workaround code above converts such  instances to `[bool]` values based on the value of their `.IsPresent` property, so as to make splatting work as intended.

    - Note the use of `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), around accessing the `.Keys` property, so as to ensure that a *static copy* of the key collection is iterated over, which permits modification of the entries of the dictionary without provoking a `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` error.