# Different results with invoke-command vs local command

Tags: powershell, certificate, invoke-command

Executing practically the same command but remotely delivers no results in Powershell.

This delivers empty lines:

```
$certificates = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My 
}

foreach ($certificate in $certificates)
{
    $certificate.FriendlyName
}
```

meanwhile this script locally on the remote computer delivers the desired results:

```
$certificates = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My 

foreach ($certificate in $certificates)
{
    $certificate.FriendlyName
}
```

I use the Invoke-Command in another script with certificates and works perfectly fine. All the other properties except FriendlyName work perfectly fine. I added all the friendly names on the certificates today, maybe the computer I run invoke-command from hasn't caught on yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Had to do this pipeline thingy for whatever reason

```
$certificates = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select FriendlyName
}

foreach ($certificate in $certificates)
{
    $certificate.FriendlyName
}
```

Comment: Remote results are in a serialized format with slightly different attributes at times

Comment: @DavidTrevor, at times they are deserialized with _static copies_ of the original objects' property values (using method-less _emulations_ of the original objects), but that doesn't explain why `.FriendlyName` isn't populated. In fact, in the case at hand they are deserialized _as their original type_, but without the `.FriendlyName` property, which smells like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your [own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77194698/45375) is effective; let me add an explanation:

###### Background information:

- In *cross-process* communication such as in PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote), *serialization* is of necessity involved.
- PowerShell uses a specialized XML format, [CLIXML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-psrp), for serialization.
- Only instances of a select few, well-known types are deserialized *as their original type*. All others are deserialized as *emulations* of the original instances, using *method-less* `[psobject]` instances that contain *static copies* of the property values of the original instances.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for background information.

---

It looks like **you've run into a *bug***:

- [`[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2) instances emitted by `Get-ChildItem Cert:...` commands *do* deserialize as their original type.
- However - and that is the bug - the `.FriendlyName` property values are *not* preserved in the process.

  - See [GitHub issue #20398](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20398)

---

**Workarounds**:

Querying the `.FriendlyName` property *at the remote source* is indeed the solution, as in your solution.

If you want to return not just that property, but *all* of the certificates' properties, pipe to [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-Property *`, which in essence emulates what the remoting serialization does for *non*-well-known types, i.e. it creates method-less *emulations* of the original objects with *static copies* of their property values:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object -Property *
} | 
  Select-Object Issuer, FriendlyName  |
  Format-List
```

The above, as an example, (also) uses `Select-Object` *client-side* to extract multiple properties of interest.