# Running an elevated powerShell command without opening an elevated prompt

Tags: windows, powershell

Just of curiosity:

When I - in my Powershell scripts - want to install or update a module or execute another command demanding elevated privileges, I can do so, from my not-elevated Powershell window, using:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process Powershell -runAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"path\to\file`" $harguments'"
```

This opens a new elevated window and I can run whatever is the file, with elevated privileges.

I just wonder if I, by any means, can execute a command demanding elevated privileges from my non-elevated prompt (so as not to open another window - just accepting the "elevated prompt" demand)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By security-minded design**, Windows itself prevents non-elevated and elevated processes from sharing a console. Therefore, **elevated (console-subsystem) processes launched from a non-elevated process *invariably* run in a *new* console window.**

There are only **suboptimal, nontrivial *workarounds*** requiring a ***helper executable*** to wrap the elevated process.
See the bottom section for the tradeoffs involved.

---

**[`gsudo.exe`](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo)** is such a helper executable, and you can **install** via `winget.exe` as follows:

```bash
# Note: Requires elevation (admin privileges) to install; prompts on demand.
#       Installs gsudo.exe as well as an effective alias, sudo.exe (via a symlink)
winget install gerardog.gsudo
```

While `gsudo` equally works from `cmd.exe` and even from WSL, it has **special support for calls *from PowerShell***:

- Note:

  - With the crucial distinction that the target process is launched *elevated*, `gsudo` *in effect* supports the same syntax as the PowerShell CLIs ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) with the (implied) `-Command` parameter (only). `gsudo` automatically uses the same PowerShell executable as the one underlying the current session.
  - If you need more control over the PowerShell CLI call that is used behind the scenes, namely to pass additional CLI options, call the CLI *directly*; e.g. `gsudo pwsh -NoProfile { net sessions }`
- You can **pass `.ps1` file paths and arguments directly**:

  ```bash
  gsudo C:\path\to\file.ps1 arg1 arg2
  ```

  - Note:

    - This invariably only supports *text* output; for rich type support, use a script block, as discussed next.
    - Also, because `-Command` is used behind the scenes, pass-through arguments, even when passed as *verbatim* strings on the caller side, are subject to interpretation *by the callee*; e.g. `gsudo C:\path\to\file.ps1 '$HOME'` is still expanded to the value of the `$HOME` variable, namely in the elevated process; you can avoid this by making an *explicit* CLI call via `-File` instead of `-Command` (e.g., `gsudo pwsh -File C:\path\to\file.ps1 '$HOME'`, or again use the script-block approach discussed next.
- You can even **pass [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)**, in which case you get the benefits of ***rich type support***, albeit with *limited type fidelity*, as is invariably the case when *cross-process serialization* is involved.<sup>[1]</sup>

  ```bash
  # Outputs a deserialized [System.Diagnostics.Process] instance, 
  # i.e. an *emulation* of the original object with static copies of
  # its properties.
  gsudo { Get-Process -IncludeUserName $args[0] } -Args winlogon
  ```

  - The equivalent of the above `.ps1` call with rich type support is (additionally, the re-interpretation of the elements of the array of pass-through arguments passed to `-Args` is prevented):

    ```bash
    gsudo { C:\path\to\file.ps1 $args[0] $args[1] } -Args arg1, arg2
    ```

---

Among the **workarounds**, there are **two mutually exclusive approaches**, each with their own pros and cons - **`gsudo` uses one or the other, as situationally appropriate**:

- Make the helper executable ***attach* the elevated process directly to the caller's console**.

  - Pro: Provides the **full console UI experience**, such as used by full-screen console applications such as [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)).
  - Con: The caller has ***no* access to the elevated process's standard streams**, i.e. you can neither send data to its stdin stream, nor can you capture its stdout and stderr streams.
  - `gsudo` uses this approach when you launch it *without arguments*, so as to enter an *interactive* elevated session.
- Make the helper executable **run the elevated process *hidden* and communicate with it via its standard streams**, printing stdout and stderr output from the elevated process to the caller's console by default..

  - Pro: **Allows sending input to and capturing output from the elevated process**.
  - Con: Lacks the full console user experience; however, for automated execution of non-interactive commands or commands with only simple console-based user prompts this won't matter.
  - `gsudo` uses this approach when you launch it *with a command* to execute.

---

<sup>[1] This the same kind of [CLIXML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-psrp)-based serialization that is used in PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) and background [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs).

The type-fidelity limitations are detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).</sup>