# Can't execute a Powershell script file

Tags: powershell, windows-10, jenv

I am tryin to use JEnv on windows 10. But I got the following error.

```
C:\dev_tools\JEnv\src\jenv.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system.
```

I tried run  `Set-ExecutionPolicy` with different options but always got error about `Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope`.  The `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` print the following result

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy 
        ----- --------------- 
MachinePolicy       AllSigned 
   UserPolicy       Undefined 
      Process          Bypass 
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned 
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

I guess I can't do anything, since I can't edit any group policy

Comment: Try launching powershell with `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **if your machine's script [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) is controlled *via GPOs* (Group Policy Objects), you can NOT override it *ad hoc*** - neither with [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) `-Scope Process Bypass -Force` nor by passing `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+).

To change the effective policy to suit your needs therefore requires modifying the relevant GPO.

Since it is the *machine-level* GPO in your case that enforces that all scripts be [*signed*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Signing), you'll need *administrative privileges* to change it.

- Note that [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy) `-List` lists the policies in order of precedence: The first policy that *isn't* `Undefined` is the *effective* one.
- It is only if *both* `MachinePolicy` and `UserPolicy` are listed as `Undefined` that the *ad hoc* overrides listed at the top are possible; you'll then also be able to change the policy for *your* account *persistently*, with `SetExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned`, for instance.

If you cannot change the GPO-based policy to suit your needs, you can try the following - ***limited* - workaround**, based on reading your script file's *content* into memory with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), parsing it into a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), and executing it via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

- **Note**: Clearly, the administrators of your machine want you to execute *signed* scripts only. It is up to you to decide whether circumventing this limitation is appropriate or not.

If your **script needs to modify the *current session***, such as setting *environment variables*, you must execute it *in-session*:

```bash
# !! This MAY or MAY NOT work.
# !! Will also exit the calling session if the script terminates with `exit`
# Pass arguments, if needed, as usual.
& ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content -Raw C:\dev_tools\JEnv\src\jenv.ps1)))
```

- **CAVEAT**: If your script terminates with  [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords#exit), the above will *exit the current session as a whole*, because that's what executing `exit` *outside of a script file* does.
- The workaround is to call via a child process, as shown next, but that invariably prevents the code from modifying the caller's session.

**If your script *doesn't* need to modify the current session, the following avoids the `exit` problem**, by executing the code in a *child process*, via a PowerShell CLI call, but comes with **additional limitations** (beyond just the performance penalty):

```bash
# !! This MAY or MAY NOT work.
# powershell is for Windows PowerShell; use pwsh in PowerShell (Core) 7+
# See below for argument-passing and data type-fidelity limitations.
powershell ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content -Raw C:\dev_tools\JEnv\src\jenv.ps1)))
```

**Limitations**:

- Fundamentally, in both cases:

  - This will only work if your script:

    - does NOT call *other* scripts.
    - does NOT (possibly implicitly) import *modules* whose loading involves execution of script (module) files (`.ps1`, `.psm1`) and/or [formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) and [type-extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml) files (`.psm1xml`).
  - Also, executing your script's code not via a *file* means that its code won't be able to reflect on its file-based identity; notably, the  [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) and the [automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) will have no values.
- Additionally, when calling via the PowerShell CLI (child process):

  - If *arguments* are to be passed to the script's code, they must be passed via the `-args` CLI parameter, `,`-separated, and they are invariably treated as *positional* arguments (in other words: you cannot pass *named* arguments this way).<sup>[1]</sup>
  - Calling via a child process invariably entails *limited data-type fidelity* - which may or not may a problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] A workaround is possible, but cumbersome; something along the lines of:

`powershell { & ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content -Raw C:\dev_tools\JEnv\src\jenv.ps1))) -FooParam $args[0] -BarParam $args[1] } -args foo, bar`</sup>